# How to specify where to read data from HDFS when submitting Spark application?

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs

I have been trying to deploy a spark multi-node cluster on three machines (master, slave1 and slave2). I have successfully deployed the spark cluster but I am confused about how to distribute my HDFS data over the slaves? Do I need to manually put data on my slave nodes and how can I specify where to read data from when submitting an application from the client? I have searched multiple forums but haven't been able to figure out how to use HDFS with Spark without using Hadoop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** Store files to be processed by a Spark application on Hadoop HDFS and Spark executors will be told how to access them.

---

From [HDFS Users Guide](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html):

> This document is a starting point for users working with Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS) either as a part of a Hadoop cluster or as a stand-alone general purpose distributed file system.
>
> A HDFS cluster primarily consists of a NameNode that manages the file system metadata and DataNodes that store the actual data.

So, HDFS is a *mere* file system that you can use to store files and use them in a distributed application, incl. a Spark application.

---

To my great surprise, it's only in [HDFS Architecture](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsDesign.html) where you can find a HDFS URI, i.e. `hdfs://localhost:8020/user/hadoop/delete/test1` that is a HDFS URL to a resource `delete/test1` that belongs to the user `hadoop`.

The URL that start with `hdfs` points at a HDFS that in the above example is managed by a NameNode at `localhost:8020`.

That means that HDFS does not require Hadoop YARN, but is usually used together because they come together and is just simple to use together.

---

> Do I need to manually put data on my slave nodes and how can I specify where to read data from when submitting an application from the client?

Spark supports Hadoop HDFS with or without Hadoop YARN. A [cluster manager](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html) (aka *master URL*) is an orthogonal concern to HDFS.

Wrapping it up, just use `hdfs://hostname:port/path/to/directory` with  to access files on HDFS.